# How to debug jmeter-server using JPDA?

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm developing plugin for JMeter and I want to connect to jmeter-server at runtime from Intellij IDEA.
 I've added to jmeter.bat the following string:

```
set JVM_ARGS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=1099, suspend=n
```

But when I try to connect, I receive the following error:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 1099
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: suspend=n
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: suspend=n
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: suspend=n.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" errorlevel=1
```

I've started jmeter and jmeter-server on the same machine, but specified port for jmeter-server.
Can you explain me, what am I doing wrong?

I tried to remove extra space in JVM_ARGS, as I was told, but still having error:

```
    Found ApacheJMeter_core.jar
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 1099
Created remote object: UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[192.168.56.1:50900](local),objID:[-6928e8c:13b637ed53e:-7fff, 6493737834091623438]]]
Problem creating registry: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
Continuing...
Server failed to start: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start. See server log file.; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException
An error occurred: Cannot start. See server log file.; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException
Debugger failed to attach: timeout during handshake
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an extra space before the `suspend` parameter which causes the JVM to interpret it as the first non-option paramter (i.e. the main class name).

Try replacing the line above with:

```
set JVM_ARGS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=1099,suspend=n
```

Comment: Thank you, Nuno, it works. Could you, please, explain(if you are able) the meaning of next parameters: server, transport, suspend?

Comment: You can find the description of all of those parameters from JPDA's latest documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html).

Comment: Thanks, clear. But I still have some issues with connecting, could you, please, take a look?

Comment: The error shows that the port (1099) is already in use by the time the RMI registry is created, because you're using that port for remote debugging as well. Try using a different port number (e.g. address=10099).